# Android: Can not connect to postgresql server via jdbc through GPRS/3G on android device, when it's okay through Wi-Fi

Tags: android, jdbc, wifi, 3g, gprs

everybody. I have a problem and have no idea why this happens. I 
 really need help.

The problem is that I can't connect to postgresql server via jdbc 
 through GPRS on my android device, when everything is fine through Wi-Fi. 
 I used this - "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexd.portscanner" and it showed that the server's IP is not 
 reachable with GPRS, but it is with Wi-Fi. But the GPRS works fine in 
 browser.

Probably the problem is not about jdbc, so any suggestions are 
 welcome. I'm new to it, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address is probably reachable, but the port Postgres is listening on might not be (it might be blocked). If there is nothing else using those ports (i.e., a Web server like Apache) on your server, you can try changing the port Posgres listens on to 80 or 443, and then specify this in your JDBC connection string. This will probably work, but using JDBC over a mobile connection might not be the best idea. Build a simple Web frontend for your data, and send receive data from/to your app using HTTP.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So if the port is blocked, it might cause fail with GPRS, but success with Wi-Fi? What's the difference between this two? Both of them use port 5432, as far as I understand.

Comment: You control your Wi-Fi (presumably), your carrier controls 3G/GPRS. They can choose to block whatever they like and there is nothing you can do about it. Regular apps and browsers mostly use HTTP/HTTPS and that is pretty much guaranteed to be allowed. Anything else might be filtered and/or throttled.